# Fourier transform of $L^1(\Bbb{R})$ functions

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, fourier-transform

> Let $f\in L^1(\Bbb{R})$ and define by $\hat f(\xi)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x)e^{-i\xi x}d\mu(x)$ the Fourier transform of $f$. Prove: $\hat f(\xi)=\frac{1}{2}(\widehat {f-f_{\frac{\pi}{\xi}}})(\xi)$, where $f_{\frac{\pi}{\xi}}=f(x-\frac{\pi}{\xi})$.

My attempt: Let $f\in L^1(\Bbb{R})$. Then:

$$(\widehat {f-f_{\frac{\pi}{\xi}}})(\xi)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}(f(x)-f_{\frac{\pi}{\xi}}(x))e^{-i\xi x}d\mu(x)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x)e^{-i\xi x}d\mu(x)-\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x-\frac{\pi}{\xi})e^{-i\xi x}d\mu(x)$$

Now if I could use the change of variables $x-\frac{\pi}{\xi}\to y$, I would get the equality I want. But I don't know if I can use change of variables in the case of Lebesgue integrals. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can use change of variable with Lebesgue (note spelling!) integrals.

Comment: @md2perpe is it obvious or does this require some explanation?

Comment: Change of variables is a theorem to be proven. There's a very general version which is also true for Lebesgue integrals. The general case is difficult, but in the case of translations, one can prove it quite easily and directly (first for indicators of intervals/ measurable sets, then for simple functions, then for non-negative measurable functions, then for all integrable functions). But anyway, rest assured that the theorem is valid (Lebesgue integrals are a strict generalization of Riemann integrals, so anything you can do with Riemann, you can do with Lebesgue).